# Import arraylist to jsp, empty result

Tags: jsp, arraylist

I have arraylist of objects. From servlet, I'm putting it to session, like that:

```
session.setAttribute("registrations", rayList);
```

Here's jsp page:

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
...     
<c:forEach var="book" items="${registrations}"> 
                                <tr> 
                                    <td>${book.bookName}</td> 
                                    <td>${book.bookAmount}</td> 
                                    <td>${book.BookName}</td> 
                                    <td>${book.bookYear}</td> 
                                     </tr> 
                            </c:forEach>
```

But there is empty, no errors, nothing happens.

But if I'll do the same with simple varible, all is ok.

Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: Well, you certainly don't need to import anything. Are you sure the list actually has contents? You've correctly included the JSTL taglib declaration?

Comment: Yes, list has content. But I'm not sure about correct taglib declaration/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: It works with simple variables, but it doesnt works with arraylist, so I think that JSTL taglib declaration is ok.

Comment: Check the generated HTML code. Maybe everything is there, but the CSS hides your rows. Or maybe the taglib is not correctly declared, and you'll see unprocessed <c:forEach> tags in the generated HTML. Also, add `empty = ${empty registrations}` or even `size = <%= ((java.util.List) session.getAttribute("registration")).size() %>` to your JSP to check if the list is there and non-empty.

Comment: @JB Nizet So HTML code looks like     'code'<c:forEach var="book" items="[helljava.listElement@fe9936, helljava.listElement@fcd0be, helljava.listElement@1ec8105]"> 
                        <tr> 
                            <td></td> 
                            <td></td> 
                            <td></td> 
                            <td></td> 
                            <td></td> 
                        </tr> 
                    </c:forEach> 'code'

Comment: That means that you haven't declared the core JSTL taglib correctly. Follow the link I posted before to see what you must add to the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with JSTL core taglib declaration.

To declare JSTL core, just add to rhe top of JSP page:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps getBookName is not a variable defined in Book class?

Make sure Book class has all the fields and setter and getters defined for bookName, bookAmount, getBookName and bookYear.

Comment: Yeap, getBookName not a variable. I've tried different ways, forgot to edit it.

Comment: And "book" - its not a class, its arrayList of objects.

Comment: -1. getBookName should not be a variable for the above to work. And there is no need for a setter either. And it the problem was an absence of getter, an exception would be thrown.

Comment: @JB Nizet - the code before edit had ${book.getBookName}, hence the question. There can be an exception thrown but his console might not be displaying it and probably a log file is complaining?

Comment: `${book.getBookName}` doesn't need a getBookName variable to work. It needs a `getGetBookName()` getter. The EL works with Java Bean propertis. Not with fields. And the exception would not go unnoticed. It would prevent the execution of the JSP and would display an error message in the browser.